# How to write text right next to a text input?

Tags: r, shiny

How to place text right next to a text input?

[image]

This is how I created the above picture:

```
   library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 3,
          div(style = "white-space: nowrap;", 
          textInput(inputId = "txt_ipt", label = "Some label text", 
                    value = "", width = 150))),
        column(
          width = 3,
          "Move me down"))),
    mainPanel()))

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My goal is to write some text (in fact only one word) right next to the text input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job, feel free to change the font-size from `h5` to `h4` and others

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 3,
          div(style = "white-space: nowrap;", 
              div(style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;",textInput("txt_ipt", label = "Some label text", value = "", width = 150)),
              h5('Move me down',style="display:inline-block")

              )))),
    mainPanel()))

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HTML()` along with `<br>` to move the text down a line. Something like:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 3,
          div(style = "white-space: nowrap;", 
          textInput(inputId = "txt_ipt", label = "Some label text", 
                    value = "", width = 150))),
        column(
          width = 3,
          HTML("<br>Move me down")))),
    mainPanel()))

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lucy's answer that does not allow for fine positioning brought me to the following solution that does:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 3,
          div(style = "white-space: nowrap;", 
              textInput(inputId = "txt_ipt", label = "Some label text", 
                        value = "", width = 150))),
        column(
          width = 3,
          tags$div(
            style="margin-top:30px;",
            "Move me down")))),
    mainPanel()))

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```